# Finding resulting domains after enforcing arc consistency

Tags: math, optimization, constraint-satisfaction-problems

This question is about the below exam scheduling constraint satisfaction graph, where each node represents a course. Each course is associated with an initial domain of possible exam days (most courses could be on Monday, Tuesday, or Wednesday; a few are already restricted to just a single day). An edge between two nodes means that those two classes must have exams on different days.

[image]

The question is: After enforcing arc consistency on this entire problem, what are the resulting domains for the variables C, D, and E?

I got the resulting domains:

```
C: {Monday}
D: {Monday, Wednesday}
E: {Tuesday}
```

and also:

C: {Monday}
D: {Monday, Wednesday}
E: {Tuesday}

But the official answer is:

C: {Monday}
D: {Monday, Wednesday}
E: {Tuesday, Wednesday}

Am I missing something? I thought since D & E are connected they can't have the same day in common in this case Wednesday.